# Are the extra buttons on my mouse gonna do their assigned functions on RDP and/or Teamviewer?

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer, logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard

I think of buying a multiple programmable button mouse (and keyboard, maybe, too)
For example the Logitech M705 Marathon Wireless Mouse with 5-Programmable Buttons.

Will I be able to use these extra programmable buttons on the Logitech mouse and keyboard on *RDP* and *Teamviewer* sessions (inside remote desktops/OSes.. consisting of Windows 10/11)?

I am gonna probably use the accompanied Logitech Software to program the buttons.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, mouse utilities run at a lower level then software, they "hook" into the OS and handle *all* mouse messages. By intercepting these messages, they work with **any** software that expects mouse input, and can even emulate other events. For example, one could send a <kbd>PgUp/</kbd> or <kbd>PgDn/</kbd> key press, as shown below.

That said, the hook is in the OS of *your local computer*, not in the remote machine, when using MS *Remote Desktop*, *Teamviewer*, or one of the [many alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/teamviewer/). Likely, the remote PC will respond appropriately to <kbd>PgUp/</kbd>, for example, but that depends on a number of factors (e.g., does the OS on the remote implement <kbd>PgUp/</kbd> in the same way as on your PC). Test to find out, and read the manual for the remote access app, to see what messages are sent.

On this PC from which I write, Logitech's own software did *not* work for an M510 mouse, but a small free third-party tool, [X-Mouse Button Control (XMBC)](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) works well.

[image: X-Mouse Button Control Setup]

Since all aspects, buttons *and* wheel, of the mouse are programmable, such software or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/x-mouse-button-control/) should let you assign each to *any* application. You can even have different profiles for different apps or users.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this for RDP/Teamviewer as in question? My local Windows 10 PC probably will easily program the buttons to work, using Logitech Software.

Comment: @user1779508, RDP depends on how the remote PC is set. Test and find out.

Comment: That's nice to hear. (I can't test yet as I don't have the mouse yet).